# First data gateway id i have but i cant find sample

Tags: php, api, payment-gateway, firstdata

I tried this for an day,but i can't find the way, i first data payment gateway information (Gateway id,DivisionID,MID) & (Key & Hmac key) and i have the form for amount the was entered then redirect to first payment gateway,but i got error only.Sample code i used.

```
<input type="hidden" value="98746"  id="ddlPOS_ExactID" name="ddlPOS_ExactID">    
<input type="text" id="tbPOS_DollarAmount" value="1" name="tbPOS_DollarAmount">    
<input type="hidden" value="00" id="ddlPOS_Transaction_Type" name="ddlPOS_ExactID">
```

and i got error of

```
Unable to proceed with payment

We cannot proceed with payment because of technical difficulties.
Please try again later
```

Please help me to find correct way.